# Contar solo registro de FILAS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola deseo hacer lo siguiente:

```
+-----+------+------+------+-----+
|Fila |Item1 |Item2 |Item3 |Item4|
+-----+------+------+------+-----+
|1    |12220 |12321 |12321 |55555|
+-----+------+------+------+-----+
|2    |1001  |002200|30220 |   0 |
+-----+------+------+------+-----+
|2    |1001  |  0   |  0   |  0  |
+-----+------+------+------+-----+
```

Quiero hacer:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM TABLE
```

Si hago eso me sale la cantidad de registros de una Tabla NO es lo que deseo.

Yo quiero algo como:

```
SELECT COUNTFILE (*) FROM TABLE WHERE FILE NOT IN (0)



Fila 1 = 4
Fila 2 = 3
Fila 3 = 1
```

Comment: ¿Los datos de tu tabla originalmente que orden tienen?, ayudaría saber ese detalle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas evaluar si el valor de tu columna es distinto de cero para asignar uno, y luego sumar todos los casos.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ITEM1 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
+ CASE WHEN ITEM2 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
+ CASE WHEN ITEM3 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
+ CASE WHEN ITEM4 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS CONTEO
FROM TABLA
```

Comment: Gracias Exelente

Comment: Si fue de ayuda por favor acepta la respuesta mediante el boton. Gracias.